# Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions. ToDo app

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I checked a lot of blogs but none got me this error solved. Can someone please explain why i am getting this error and the remedy.
I am new to redux. I was following all the commands given by a youtube video. In that video he is not using dispatch anywhere. Can you also tell me where to use dispatch.
src/index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'
import {createStore} from 'redux';
import reducers from './reducer/'
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

const store=createStore(reducers);

ReactDOM.render(
<Provider store={store}>
  <App />
</Provider>
  ,
  document.getElementById('root'));
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

action/index.js

```
const addTask=(task)=>{
  return{
    type:'ADD_TASK',
    payload:task
  }
}
const deleteTask=(taskId)=>{
  return{
    type:'DELETE_TASK',
    payload:taskId
  }
}
export  {addTask,deleteTask};
```

task/index.js

```
import React from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux'
import {addTask} from '../../actions/'
import {deleteTask} from '../../actions/'

class Task extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <tr>
      <td>
      {this.props.task1}
      </td>
      <td>
      <button onCLick={()=> this.props.dispatch(deleteTask(this.props.id))}>delete</button>
      </td>
      </tr>
    )
  }
}
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
  return (bindActionCreators({deleteTask},dispatch))
}
export default connect(()=>{},mapDispatchToProps)(Task)
```

taskbar/index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux'
import {addTask} from '../../actions/index'
class Taskbar extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
      <input type="text" ref="task" placeholder="add your task" />
      <button onClick={()=>this.props.dispatch(addTask(this.refs.task.value))}> ADD TASK</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
  return bindActionCreators({addTask},dispatch);
}
export default connect(()=>{},bindActionCreators)(Taskbar) ;
```

tasklist/index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import Task from '../task';
class Tasklist extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
      <table>
      <thead>
      <tr>
      <th>Tasks</th>
      <th>Actions</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
      {this.props.tasks.map((t,i)=> <Task key={i} task1={t} />)}
      </tbody>
      </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
function mapStateToProps (state){
return{  tasks: state.tasks
};
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Tasklist);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error info you are facing:

> Use custom middleware for async actions.

Follow it and add **applyMiddleware** to your `createStore`.

```js
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

(async () => {
  const preloadStore = {
  };

  const store = createStore(
    reducer,
    preloadStore,
    composeWithDevTools(
      applyMiddleware(thunk)
    )
  );
..
```

Comment: If you use thunk for res/req, you code like that (notice `import thunk from 'redux-thunk'`), otherwise use your libs and refer to their document. This answer is only used for explanation of what you are lacking.